# Adding HTML5 placeholder attribute to spring 3.0 form input elements

Tags: spring, jsp, html, spring-mvc

How do I add HTML5 placeholder attributes to Spring webmvc's form:input, form:password and form:textarea elements?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As of Spring 3.0 form tags support dynamic attributes, therefore you can simply write

```
<form:input placeholder = "..." ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the new input types question - I had success by using spring bind and manually generating the input element. I'm using bootstrap so I already had a tag to wrap the control-group and apply the error message, but if you just want to inline it you can do the following.

if your `path` field was 'age', replace `<form:input path="age"/>` with

```
<spring:bind path="age">
  <input id="age" name="age" type="number" value="${status.value}" />
</spring:bind>
```