# How to use HTML5 tags and attributes in spring MVC

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Recently learnt HTML5 new tags and attributes. But how will i be able to use with Spring MVC. Till now all spring mvc jsp pages does not have support for HTML5.

For example if i want to use video/audio tags and attributes with spring MVC, how can i achieve it?

A simple example would be using `placeholder` attribute of html 5 with `<form:input>` tag of spring MVC. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring doesn't care what tags you use in your jsp files. The browser does.
Use a correct document type for HTML5 is all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: But how can i use it with spring tags like `<form.input>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232983/adding-html5-placeholder-attribute-to-spring-3-0-form-input-elements