# Set Default value if path value is null

Tags: java, jsp

How to set input field default value if fieldDisplayName_UserName is null

```
<td><form:input type="text" path="fieldDisplayName_UserName" id="fieldDisplayName_UserName" onblur="if (this.value == '') 
{this.value = 'User Name';}" 
onfocus="if (this.value == 'User Name') {this.value = '';}" /></td>
```

I am trying

```
<td><form:input type="text" path="fieldDisplayName_UserName" 
id="fieldDisplayName_UserName" onblur="if (this.value == '') 
{this.value = 'User Name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'User Name') {this.value = '';}" value="User Name"/></td>
```

but this value always shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set a `placeholder` like it is suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232983/adding-html5-placeholder-attribute-to-spring-3-0-form-input-elements)