# How do you put value or placeholder in form:input Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

hi I would like to know how to place a attribute "value","defaultValue" or "placeholder" from form:input

Original Code

```
 <form:input path="ggpath" cssStyle="width:100%"/>
```

What I want

```
 <form:input path="ggpath" cssStyle="width:100%" value="example"/>
```

but if I place value attribute. It does give me an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232983/adding-html5-placeholder-attribute-to-spring-3-0-form-input-elements

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
<form:input path="ggpath" style="width:100%" placeholder="example"/>
```

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo Updated the answer. Try it now

Comment: Invalid Attribute Placeholder

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo which version of spring are you using?

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo also show the full error stack trace that is showing up at your end

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep that default value in command object like

private string ggpath="example";

This will be displayed as default value in the form. From spring 3.0 you can use placeholder tag also directly